# Ubuntu Modoboa from NGINX to APACHE2: HttpS 403 forbidden while HTTP is correctly accessible. (mod_WSGI)

Tags: python, linux, apache, ubuntu, nginx

Resources:

- LINUX UBUNTU 20.04
- Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server Port 443
- Certbot verified HTTPS.
- Latest version of Modoboa installed by the tutorial of mod_wsgi (sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3)
- in HTTP the sites loads of Modoboa and is accessible *(so this means python3 installation all good everything working fine in Apache2)*.

**Problem:**

- in HTTPS it returns:

  **403
  Forbidden
  You don't have permission to access this resource.**
  *(when I try to access it as httpS://mail.domain.nl, but without S, so http://mail.domain.nl is accessible)*

Things I tried to solve the problem so far:
In `/srv`, I have executed `$ sudo chmod -R 777 modoboa`.

But this error is still there, as in it is only through HTTP accessible but not through HTTPS URL.
Does anyone know why? Since I cannot login in HTTP because of security reasons, I need to use HTTPS for the mail server.

The conf file is like this: :D

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mail.domain.nl
  ServerAlias www.mail.domain.nl
  DocumentRoot /srv/modoboa/instance/

  Alias /media/ /srv/modoboa/instance/media/
  <Directory /srv/modoboa/instance/media>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /sitestatic/ /srv/modoboa/instance/sitestatic/
  <Directory /srv/modoboa/instance/sitestatic>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/modoboa/instance/instance/wsgi.py

  <Directory "/srv/modoboa/instance">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
  </Directory>

   WSGIDaemonProcess mail.domain.nl python-path=/srv/modoboa/instance/:/srv/modoboa/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
   WSGIProcessGroup mail.domain.nl

  # Pass Authorization header to enable API usage:
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>
```

*Oh and domain.nl is a placeholder for publishing this document, in reality it has the domain which I use the webserver on :D.*

---

Some emotional background story :D:D:D:D:D:
I am new to Linux, I have always been a fanboy of Windows because I didn't understand Linux (you know hate the unknown).
Since few months at my Student Association, there is one guy a diehard Linux fan and he pushed us to use Linux for our website. Since then I found it actually very comfortable, since it was also way more cheaper than Windows server I decided to use it. I have multiple Wordpress websites hosted at APACHE2 in UBUNTU 20.04, I would also like to have my own mail server and MODOBOA is verrrry beautiful upon installing, everything worked fine in NGINX but I tried to host it on APACHE2 (since I turned off apache2 while it was installing to see that it works in NGINX), after executing that sudo command to install mod_wsgi the site is accessible at HTTP but not in HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you only have a vhost listening on port 80. You need to create another vhost and have it listen on 443 which is HTTPS.

Comment: Ah I see after installing SSL with certbot, certbot made another config file named "...-le-ssl-.conf" aka port 443 vhost conf file, this didn't update along automatically when I had modified the port 80 vhost conf file. Thank you!

I have now a ratelimit of certbot I will try to let you know tomorrow after "next Letsencrypt certificate: 2020-10-22 11:05:45" I get the chance to make a new SSL attempt :p

Comment: Thanks that was the problem there was a copy at port 443, and I tried to give permission by just editting port 80 file so only at port 80 was visible hahaha.

But also I removed some major errors in Virtual Host conf file, because WSGI cannot be defined multiple times. Thank you!
I have now a second problem it says in red "dovecot.service active failed" when I look at services and when I access my mailbox Modoboa says: Error: Connection to IMAP server failed: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I will start a new stackoverflow thread in sha Allah (by God His will).
Thank you I have approved.